# How do I check if I have already filed my taxes [Unites States]

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I don't know if I've filed my taxes or not!  I am due a refund according to TaxACT Deluxe, but I have no idea how to check if I have already filed for my taxes?

What happens if I e-file again and I *have* filed for taxes?

How do I check if I need to file again?

Thanks!

Comment: If you efile again after filing before your new submission will be rejected.

Answer (score 4):

You can find a record of past tax returns on the [Get Transcript](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/Get-Transcript) page on irs.gov.

Update: As of 2016 it looks like that link only allows you to retrieve previous tax returns by mail. Previously it had allowed you to view and download them from their website.

Comment: I wrote more about this service and how to use it here: http://littleadvisor.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/great-new-service-from-the-irs-get-your-account-transcripts-online/

Comment: BTW your second paragraph is wrong. Filing 1040 after filing it previously will be rejected.

Comment: Edited out the 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

The IRS has a website called [Where is my refund?](http://www.irs.gov/Refunds)

> Get up-to-date refund information using Where's My Refund? or the
>   IRS2Go mobile app. Where's My Refund? is updated once every 24 hours,
>   usually overnight. Refunds are generally issued within 21 days after
>   we receive your tax return. You should only call if it has been
>   longer.

I don't know what information you see on this site if you owe them money.

Are you expecting a check from them, or did you send them money electronically? If you sent them money you should check your bank or card statement.

Comment: I don't know what if anything I sent them.